# why do we need httpclient handler when testing APIs

Tags: c#, api, http, testing

API calls are still working as expected without passing the handler so I don't understand when it should be passed? is it needed when we need to maintain the cookies for further requests or that can be also done without passing it

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    CookieContainer = cookies
};

_client = new HttpClient();
```

Comment: A handler is needed whenever you need unusual handling, such as cookies or compression, otherwise a default handler is used. I note you are not actually passing the handler in, you should do `_client = new HttpClient(handler);`

Comment: @Charlieface okay, that makes sense, yes I removed passing the handler to see if it's gonna affect anything. thank you!